# group objects with same field value

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I've got two models like these:

```
class Schedule(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_('name'), blank=True, max_length=15)


class Day(models.Model):
    DAYS_OF_THE_WEEK = (
        (0, _('Monday')),
        (1, _('Tuesday')),
        (2, _('Wednesday')),
        (3, _('Thursday')),
        (4, _('Friday')),
        (5, _('Saturday')),
        (6, _('Sunday')),
    )
    schedule = models.ForeignKey(Schedule, blank=True, null=True, verbose_name=_('schedule'))
    day = models.SmallIntegerField(_('day'), choices=DAYS_OF_THE_WEEK)
    opening = models.TimeField(_('opening'), blank=True)
    closing = models.TimeField(_('closing'), blank=True)
```

It's possible that a schedule can have two Day objects like so:

Day(schedule=1, day=0, opening=datetime.time(7, 30), closing=datetime.time(10, 30))
Day(schedule=1, day=0, opening=datetime.time(12, 30), closing=datetime.time(15, 30))

like different shifts on the same day.

If I iterate them now i'll get two entries of day 0, like so
    [day for day in schedule]
    [0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

How can I create a queryset so it'll group same days together and keep their attributes?

```
[day for day in schedule]
[0 (two entries), 1, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Maybe something like

```
[id: [day], id: [day]]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The code I ended up using is this:

```
from itertools import groupby

day_set = store.schedule_set.all()[0].day_set.all()
    schedule = dict()
    for k, v in groupby(day_set, lambda x: x.day):
        schedule[k] = list(v)
```

and sending schedule to the template for rendering, which works like a charm.

Comment: Probably worth noting that this works only when your stuff is already sorted (`groupby` only removed duplicate elements that are adjacent). That behavior surprised me the first time I ran into it :-/

Answer (score 4):

You can group them at template level, using [{% regroup %}](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup) or `{% for %}`-loop with [{% ifchanged %}](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#ifchanged) tag.

In Python code use [groupby](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby).

Comment: I forgot to mention I didn't want to do it in template code, rather in view 'cause it seemed expensive. But you steered me right with groupby in itertools tools. Thanks alot mate!